# How to set up an Angular routerLink to route both the primary and aux outlets

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I've tried every possible syntax for [routerLink] and I can't seem to get this to work. Here are my routes:

```
const ROUTES = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'sign-in',
    component: SignInComponent,
    outlet: 'signin'
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'projects',
    component: ProjectsComponent
  }
];
```

The main template has:

```
<header class="header">
<header class="header">
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <utility-navigation></utility-navigation>
    <navigation></navigation>
    <router-outlet name="signin"></router-outlet>
</header>
<main>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

This link pops a component into the "signin" outlet:

```
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { signin: ['sign-in'] } }]">Sign in</a>
```

This link empties the "signin" outlet and routes to the "register" component in the primary outlet:

```
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { primary: ['register'], signin: null } }]">Register</a>
```

But I want users who are currently at the `/register` route to be able to click a link to go to `/home` and also see the 'sign-in' route in the aux outlet. I've tried:

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { primary: 'home', signin: 'sign-in' }}]">
```

and

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { primary: ['home'], signin: ['sign-in'] }}]">
```

and

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { primary: 'home', signin: ['sign-in'] }}]">
```

and

```
<a [routerLink]="['/home', { outlets: { signin: ['sign-in'] }}]">
```

And they all result in an error along the lines of "cannot match any routes". I know the 'sign-in' route works because I see it when I click the "Sign in" link above. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: can you try giving `/home` as path instead of `home`

Comment: In which version? I did have /home in the last one I listed.

Comment: I tried using /home for the primary route in the second version I listed, but no go. The error is "Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'register'"